# lead + contact relation \ how to maintain life cycle in 3rd party app

Tags: contact, lead-conversion

in my 3rd party app I'd like to maintain the "life-cycle" of every prospect.
Is there a way to "understand" from contact, which lead ID it was before (for example, "history" purposes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information does not reside on the Contact record but, for a given Contact, you can find the Lead it came from and when it was converted.

The relevant fields on Lead are:

- ConvertedAccountId
- ConvertedContactId
- ConvertedDate
- ConvertedOpportunityId

From those, you can probably get all the history you need.